# Running AngularJS App on Internet Explorer 7

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-7

Just to make sure if AngularJS works on the browsers I need, I made a simple data-binging demo that works fine on Firefox, Chrome an IE8+ but I also need to make it work on IE7. Unfortunatelly I can't make it work on it. It only shows the html with the curly braces on it, ignoring `ng-` attributes.

I have checked [several](http://gpiot.com/angularjs-on-ie7-not-working-how-to-fix-it/) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464742/angularjs-and-internet-explorer) [about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984223/angularjs-data-binding-issue-on-internet-explorer-using-curly-braces) [AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709745/angular-routing-not-working-in-ie7) on Internet Explorer and tried the suggested fixes on each one but nothing works on my demo.

This is the HTML of my demo:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Angular IE7 Test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularjs/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularjs/json3.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script language="JavaScript" src="angularjs/angular.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="angularjs/test.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="ng-app">
    <div ng-controller="serversCtrl">
        <p>{{texto}}</p>

        <table border="1">
            <tbody>
                <tr><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th><th>Col3</th></tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in items"><td>{{item.col1}}</td><td>{{item.col2}}</td><td>{{item.col3}}</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the test.js javascript containing the controller and the models:

```
function serversCtrl($scope, $http, $location) {
    $scope.texto = "Texto dinamico";
    $scope.items = [
        {col1: "foo1", col2: "bar1", col3: "baz1"},
        {col1: "foo2", col2: "bar2", col3: "baz2"},
        {col1: "foo3", col2: "bar3", col3: "baz3"},
        {col1: "foo4", col2: "bar4", col3: "baz4"},
        {col1: "foo5", col2: "bar5", col3: "baz5"}
    ];
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there any other tip to make it work that I have missed?

**EDIT:** I'm using  AngularJS v1.0.5

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After some more reading I could make it work.

The problem with IE7 was the bootstrapping. It was not firing any! so I made a manual initialization as shown in [this page](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap) and it worked.

This is the code I added to the HTML assuring it will only fire on Internet Explorer 8 or lower (because if I fire it for all browsers some event handlers fire twice for non-ie browsers):

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        angular.bootstrap(document);
    });
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

The `$document.ready()` part is the jQuery way to be sure this code will be executed when everything on the body has been loaded but since I was using jQuery on my site I took advantage of it.

Comment: Could you please show me a JSFiddle or Plnkr example? I can't get his working and I would really appreciate a working example.

Answer (score 62):

1) Add `id="ng-app"` to your body tag.

```
<body ng-app="myApp" id="ng-app">
```

2) Inform your users/client it's 2013.

Comment: Actually I also tried with id="ng-app" as an alternative to class="ng-app" but none of them solved my problem. In my country (El Salvador) people still use Windows XP and Internet Explorer 6 and 7 unfortunatelly but we aree in the process of convincing them to upgrade. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: `id="ng-app"` is not meant as alternative. Both are needed, `ng-app="myApp"`and `id="ng-app"`.

Comment: @RobertoLinares - I thought they used nothing but Linux and Firefox outside of the USA.  ;-)

Comment: @AdamNofsinger According to the user agent logs on my site, there's still plenty of users here using IE6 and 7, specially goverment/big companies users.

Comment: The latest release of Angular-seed has `<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">` would that be ok on its own?

Comment: @JGallardo I don't know. Try it.

Comment: It's 2017 and still we can find users using ie7 :/