# 3px border-radius has different look in IE and other browsers

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer-9, css

This CSS produce different results in latest browsers:

```
input {
    border:1px solid #ccc;

    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

The radius size in IE is smaller:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the IE specific value by 1px,

border-radius: 4px; (instead of 3px)

Answer (score 2):

The versions of IE till 8.0 doesnot support `Border-radius` as far as i know. So I used transparent `PNG` images which I have created instead of `Div`'s which needs `border-radius` and also it solved the browser compatibility issues.

EDIT For IE9: you may be using [quirks mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529728/html5-doctype-putting-ie9-into-quirks-mode) that's why it is not compatible.

Comment: The OP tagged his question with "IE9". IE9 supports `border-radius`. See [quirks mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html).