# h:commandButton with css not the same in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, jsf-2

I have a h:commandButton with  `styleClass="waiButton"`. The generated html is

```
<input class="waiButton" type="submit" value="Add existing" name="detailForm:j_idt184">
```

In the css I have the following:

```
a.waiButton, a.waiButton:link, a.waiButton:visited, input.waiButton[type="submit"], input.waiButton[type="button"]
{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #C7E4F7;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    color: #000000;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 11pt;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Can someone tell me why in all browser but IE my buttons are displayed this way (the wanted one)
[image]

and in IE this way
[image]

In FF with Firebug I can see that the button has the right style assigned, while in IE (F12) the style is not assigned...

What is different with IE? Any hint will be appreciated.

EDIT:

The doctype is there:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

EDIT 2:

As said, the DOCTYPE is set, but I noticed something strange: clicking F12 in FF I see in the page code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

while in IE

```
<!-- DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" -->
```

Could this `<!Doctype` vs `<!--DOCTYPE` be the problem?

If yes, why IE set it as a comment? In my code there is `<!DOCTYPE` ...

Comment: just guessing, did you mention doctype at starting of the html code?

Comment: is this issue appears in all versions of IE or Specific IE Version?

Comment: Your CSS is applied from IE7 (in Standards mode only) on, except `border-radius`, which has been introduced in version 9 in IEs.

Comment: @Mr_Green: The doctype is defined (see edit in question)

Comment: I'm using IE9 and the behavior is the same in compatibility mode too.

Comment: Please take a look at the console, IE finds errors from your DTD.

Comment: @Teemu : no errors in the console...

Comment: Like said, [your code](http://jsfiddle.net/YJzvx/) works in IE > 7, except `border-radius` which you can see only in IE > 8... If I put your DTD into a file, IE10 says something like: "`HTML1524: Invalid doctype, the shortest possible doctype definition is <!DOCTYPE html>.`"

Comment: ... or, [combatibility view settings](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13287226/1169519) in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem found. I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529728/html5-doctype-putting-ie9-into-quirks-mode) that if you have an HTML comments before the DOCTYPE declaration, this will trigger the quirks mode.

I shifted the DOCTYPE declaration at the top and now it works...

Answer (score 1):

The `border-radius` property is supported only for IE9+ browsers.
For the css attribute selector `input.waiButton[type="submit"]` to work for IE8 and earlier browsers, a [!DOCTYPE](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp) must be declared.