# .net Webbrowser control display not the same

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

Hello i have a problems in my webbrowser control.

The page aren't displaying like in ie

[image: a busy cat] 
And
[image: a busy cat]

As you see the top menu isn't working , and many website are glitched

Comment: Is that second image from IE on the same computer?

Comment: This is the way it is supposed to be; it is out-of-the box functionality.  If you want it to look like IE (and why on Earth would you want that?), YOU will have to build the menu items and functionality yourself.

Comment: @Brian: I'm pretty sure the OP is talking about the massive differences in the actual rendering.  Not about IE's menus.

Comment: I thought the WebBrowser control just used IE's rendering engine? Am I wrong?

Comment: I am not talking about the control , i am talking about the rendering ! and yes its on the same computer

Comment: Here we go: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/03/10/more-ie8-extensibility-improvements.aspx Wonder if this applies to IE9/10 too and would explain the problem

Comment: @JasonSimard, Chris Lively - Quoted from the post, "As you see the top menu isnt working".  As to the rendering issue, that is a whole other can o'worms.

Comment: @Brain: That would be the menu containing the options "hot", "trending", "vote" and "top".  You know, the menu that's actually in the web page.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: @ChrisLively - If that is the case, I stand corrected.  Regardless, (and because I now get what he is asking), +1.

Comment: Is this a windows forms application, or WPF?

Comment: @JasonSimard, a very similar question on IE and `WebBrowser` rendering [answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18802626/1768303).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way this can occur is if the browser decides to render in compatibility mode.  Meaning IE decides to fix the web developers garbage whereas the webbrowser control doesn't do this automatically.

The best thing to do would be to use the right html doc type in the site.  Of course, we all know that most "web programmers" have no idea what that means, and you likely have no control of the sites people are likely to visit with your app.

That said, check out the following.  It shows how to inject a header into the web page as you are loading it in order to force the webbrowser control to use compatibility mode.

**update**  decided the link wasn't that great.

see this one instead:
[How do I turn off Compatibility View on the IE WebBrowserControl in a WinForms app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717055/how-do-i-turn-off-compatibility-view-on-the-ie-webbrowsercontrol-in-a-winforms-a)

Comment: And buried in one of the answers there was http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28VS.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation with updated registry key values for IE10 too