# which version the webBrowser engine in VS 2012 is

Tags: visual-studio-2012, browser

This is a newbie question about what is the version of the built-in webBrowser engine in visual studio 2012, it says 4.5.0 or something but i mean corresponding to Internet Explorer versions, is it IE 8, 9 or 10.

and if it is IE 8 or 9, is it possible to embed some other browser engine like Chrome or Firefox?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't have VS2012 but you can easily find out yourself, just make a new project, drop a Webbrowser, set URL to http://whatsmyuseragent.com/ and look what it says. In VS2010 it is Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0;... so IE 7

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that i have VS 2010 too and i was wondering about the newer version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've downloaded **VS 2013** and "surprisingly" the User Agent was **MSIE 7.0** still, nothing changed since the prior versions.. Thanks Microsoft!

---

**UPDATE 2015**

I've just downloaded **VS 2015** couple days ago and did the same, set the webBrowser URL to [whatsmyuseragent.com](http://whatsmyuseragent.com) page and shockingly the User Agent String result was:

> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; **MSIE 7.0**; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)

SO I decided to use this website [www.whatismybrowser.com](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/) instead and I got this:

[image]

So it was IE11 but the problem is with the IE7 compatibility view which ruins it everytime, this why the [previous website](http://whatsmyuseragent.com) was showing **MSIE 7.0** in the userAgent, and I guess the same was true for **VS 2010**, **VS 2012** and **VS 2013**.

---

To "force" rendering the webpage in the latest IE -*or versions other than the IE7 compatible one*- one of the following could be done:

1. ***First* :** if you have a specific webpage/website to display in the embedded webBrowser and you have control over it add this `meta` tag to the header:

   ```
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   ```

   Where `IE=edge` *causes the browser control to render the content in the highest available document mode*.
2. ***Second* :** for targeting a specific version of the browser, you can use the [FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee330730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation) registry key.

---

For detailed information:

- *[MSDN - Controlling webBrowser control compatibility.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2015/01/12/controlling-webbrowser-control-compatibility.aspx)*
- *[How do I turn off Compatibility View on the IE WebBrowserControl in a WinForms app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717055/how-do-i-turn-off-compatibility-view-on-the-ie-webbrowsercontrol-in-a-winforms-a)*