# TWebBrowser in Delphi XE2 ignores box-sizing CSS

Tags: css, delphi, twebbrowser

I'm using TWebBrowser to preview generated HTML pages and was using the CSS box-sizing:border-box to specify the box model and trying to use display:table display:table-cell vertical-align:middle to achieve vertically aligned text.

The problem is that while ordinary IE10 or IE11 applies this CSS, giving nicely sized and centred text, the TWebBrowser in my program doesn't.

Comment: MSIE embedded uses interanet-compatibility mode, thet means uses MSIE-6 mode. MSIE-6 i think did not supported those CSS goodies. Your app has to opt out of MSIE-6 mode i think.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/03/10/more-ie8-extensibility-improvements.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/03/18/webbrowser-control-rendering-modes-in-ie8.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717055 and maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097593/

Comment: @Arioch - that's got it! Would you like to make that an answer so I can mark it accepted. Many thanks.

Comment: I'd actually would like to make it a dup, but do not know which question to link as duplicate

Comment: Looks to be closest to 6717055

Comment: Voting to leave open as per http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139961/whats-the-policy-on-closing-unique-questions-with-overlapping-but-non-duplicat  The question is about the specific (and quite common) symptom and may be valuable to others.