# gradient filter not working in IWebBrowser2 in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, gradient, iwebbrowser2

I have a toolbar in IE that shows a html page in an embedded IWebBrowser2 control.
It works with pretty much any html,css and javascript except that the microsoft-specific filters (such as the gradient filter) don't work in IE8 on WinXP.

The odd thing is that if I load the same html into the main browser window, the gradient filter works. But if I load it into the IWebBrowser2 that's embedded in the toolbar, it doesn't.

Do you have any ideas what the reason might be?

The relevant css looks like this:

```
{
  background-color: inherit;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f1f6fd', endColorstr='#e4effd',GradientType=0 );
  height: 28px;
  padding-top:3px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
}
```

I've tried various compatibility settings as described here: [How do I turn off Compatibility View on the IE WebBrowserControl in a WinForms app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717055/how-do-i-turn-off-compatibility-view-on-the-ie-webbrowsercontrol-in-a-winforms-a)
but it makes no difference.

I appreciate any brilliant ideas you might have!

Thank you!