# wpf webbrowser can't open Polymer demos

Tags: c#, wpf, internet-explorer-11, polymer

I am new to web technologies and therefore curious why I can't open/show/render websites which are created with [the polymer framework](http://www.polymer-project.org).

I tried it with `System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser` and Awesomium WebControl. Other sites can be opened without problems, but when I try to navigate to the samples on the polymer site like [the paper calculator demo](http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-calculator/demo.html) or [the topeka demo](http://www.polymer-project.org/apps/topeka/)
I get a white blank page or just the 'splash screen'. Opening these sites with internet explorer or chrome work fine.

I'm running Windows 8.1 Pro with IE Version 11.

Comment: IE embedding typically runs in compatibility mode.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply ! Tried to disable the compatibility mode like in the [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717055/how-do-i-turn-off-compatibility-view-on-the-ie-webbrowsercontrol-in-a-winforms-a). But still got the same behaviour :(

Answer (score 0):

What version of IE is being used? Polymer only supports IE 10+

Comment: Going further with this question, the version of IE used will depend on the version of Windows. You'll need to be on at least Windows 7 for Polymer (and many other modern web tools) to work with any Internet Explorer based browser.

Comment: Just looked it up. Using IE Version 11 on Windows 8.1 Pro.