# Delphi TWebbrowser , google wants to update browser

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser, auth0

i had to change code of an older Delphi application in D2007. I required a login screen that was online (with Auth0) , in wich i could read the state of the result and according to that do some license handling.

The problem is, that whenever i try to login with Google Social account , it results in an information screen that wants me to update my browser.

The app is a Win32 app , running on Win32 and Win64 devices. I had tried to work with this solution :
[How to have Delphi TWebbrowser component running in IE9 mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25843845/how-to-have-delphi-twebbrowser-component-running-in-ie9-mode)
But any DWORD value i give to my exe , it just doesn't help me get rid of the notification.

I've been looking to use TChromium instead of TWebBrowser, but it seems buggy to me.

Are there any other ways to deal with this issue? Thanx

Comment: Does this happen when you browse to every site or just specific ones. And if just specific ones don't we need to know the details to help.

Comment: Interesting, I've never heard someone call TChromium buggier than TWebBrowser... that's actually the reason many devs switch to Chromium.

Comment: It only happens when i try to login to my google account. Which will be the case since the frame will hold an OAuth login screen.

I think it's mostly the lack of a good documentation for Chromium that holds me back from using it. Anyhow, i think it's the only option we'll have to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

If you use DWORD values mentioned in the linked topic then TWebBrowser would be working in IE9 emulation mode. And since IE9 is considered as being old various sites will advise you to update your browser.

So what you need is to make sure that TWebBrowser in your app is running in IE11 emulation mode instead.

Based on information found here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx

you should use DWORD value of `00011000` instead for full IE11 emulation.

Comment: Tried any possible browser DWORD values, none of them worked in any combination with DocType