# TWebBrowser crashes with MOST html files

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

I am using the uHTMLEdit.pas provided in RadPHP 3 as HTML editor (based on TWebbrowser).
When I load some HTML files the program crashes. As an example, save this **StackOverflow** page and load it in TWebbrowser. It will crash:

Crash details:

```
Access violation at address 005FAF9B in module 'TestHtmlEditRad.exe'. Read of address 00000000.
```

Crash on line `Doc.Body.SetAttribute('contentEditable', 'true', 0)`:

```
procedure THTMLEdit.EditText(const text: string);
VAR
  Doc: IHTMLDocument2;
  sl: TStringList;
  f: string;
begin
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  TRY
    sl.Text := text;
    f := gettempfile('.html');
    sl.SaveToFile(f);
    wbBrowser.Navigate(f);
    Doc := GetDocument;
    if Doc <> NIL
    then Doc.Body.SetAttribute('contentEditable', 'true', 0);  **Crash HERE**
    DeleteFile(f);
  FINALLY
    FreeAndNil(sl);
  END;
end;
```

It works with small (not so complex) HTML files.

My question is: Is normal for TWebBrowser to crash?

---

To reproduce you only need this code and the uHTMLEdit.pas (already provided with Embarcadero RadPHP).

```
unit FormMain;
interface
USES
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.StdCtrls, uHTMLEdit;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  end;
var
  Form1: TForm1;

IMPLEMENTATION {$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
VAR debug: string;
begin
  debug:= stringfromfile('test.htm');  // this temporary line of code is mine, for testing. All other code is Embarcadero's
  with THTMLEditDlg.Create(application) do begin
        try
            edittext(debug);
            if ShowModal= 0 
            then debug:= getText;
        finally
            free;
        end;
    end;
end;
end.
```

Comment: The AV is probably b/c either Doc or Body are not instantiated yet at the moment you call `Doc.Body.SetAttribute`. I know nothing about uHTMLEdit.pas. Try to load your file directly into a `TWebBrowser` and then set it's: `Body.SetAttribute...` on the document complete event. remember that by default the TWebBrowser uses IE7 compatibility mode. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25843845/how-to-have-delphi-twebbrowser-component-running-in-ie9-mode

Comment: Also, to switch into edit mode you can also try `Doc.DesignMode := 'On'` after the document is fully loaded.

Comment: @kobik-I don't think this is the reason. The code works for some files. So, Doc is instantiated.

Comment: Well, test it then. e.g. `if Assigned....` for both Doc and Body.

Comment: @kobik Maybe DesignMode=on will help. I will try it. Thanks. PS: I added some code from uHTMLEdit.

Comment: After you edit, `wbBrowser.Navigate(f);` is **asynchronous**. You need to wait for a ReadyState of READYSTATE_COMPLETE. or use the DocumentComplete event. IMO, this code is poorly written.

Comment: @kobik - This is code from Embarcadero's HTML editor (used in RadPHP which is indeed super unstable). Tanks again. This might be the solution!

Comment: Except for the line "s:= stringfromfile" (which is there temporary, for easy debugging) all code is Embarcadero's. I don't know why they use a temp file.

Comment: @kobik - I will accept your answer "you need to wait for a ReadyState..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `THTMLEdit.EditText` method:

```
...
wbBrowser.Navigate(f);
Doc := GetDocument;
if Doc <> NIL
then Doc.Body.SetAttribute('contentEditable', 'true', 0);  **Crash HERE**
...
```

`wbBrowser.Navigate(f)` is **asynchronous**. When you call `Doc.Body.SetAttribute` either `Doc` or `Doc.Body` *might* not be ready/instantiated yet. this is the cause of the AV.

Since `Navigate` is asynchronous, You need to wait for the `TWebBrowser` to fully load and initialize its DOM. This is commonly done by e.g.:

```
  wbBrowser.Navigate(f);
  while wbBrowser.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE do
    Application.ProcessMessages;
  ...
```

Since `Application.ProcessMessages` considered to be "evil", and may cause re-entrance issues (unless You handle it correctly), a better approach should be to use the [`TWebBrowser.OnDocumentComplete`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SHDocVw_TWebBrowser_OnDocumentComplete.html) event where the document/frame is fully loaded, and access the (ready/initialized) DOM there.