# Disable Google Maps user agent check

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, twebbrowser

Starting with version 3.29, the Google Maps JavaScript API checks the browser's `navigator.userAgent` and shows a compatibility warning.

I'm displaying a map in an embedded web browser control. By default, the control runs in IE 7 compatibility mode -- I can override that with an `X-UA-Compatible` tag. The page looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <style>
       #map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
       }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {});
      }
    </script>

    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.29&key=~APIKEY~&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

With the meta tag at the top, the page renders in IE 11 mode, but it still uses this user agent:

> User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.3)

I can override what HTTP User-Agent is sent, but I can't change the JavaScript `navigator.userAgent` property. Is there a way to disable Google's check without disabling warnings completely?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone with a similar issue, you can hide all warnings on the page like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .infomsg { display: none; }
</style>
```

But I'd like to find a better solution.

Comment: This does not seem to work any more. The message disappears, but the map will not be loaded.