# TWebBrowser in Delphi 10.2 doesn't show a form as it should

Tags: forms, delphi, webbrowser-control

I make a multi-device app that has a TWebBrowser component.
If i write this code

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate('https://google.com');
```

it opens the form as it should be.
But if i write this code

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate(edit1.text);
```

where edit1.text=the URL of a GoogleForms form (=https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScLDCv_LeYJzvMoxnmvt_gN_gqeup7_vbU8VLaC-qXNPEGMIQ/viewform?vc=0&c=0&w=1&fbzx=3551763952707733753), it shows the form confused (the dropdown components as list of text, the "submit" button as text etc) like this :

[image]

is there a solution, please ?

PS. the form is opened in Internet Explorer (and Google) right.

Comment: Whar are the **exact** contents of `Edit1.Text`?

Comment: Can we see your HTML? And what URL you're using to open it?

Comment: the URL in Edit1.text is this : https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScLDCv_LeYJzvMoxnmvt_gN_gqeup7_vbU8VLaC-qXNPEGMIQ/viewform?vc=0&c=0&w=1&fbzx=3551763952707733753

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this happens is that by default TWebBrowser component is opening web pages in compatiblity mode. This prevents myn moder web pages to show properly.

So in order to avoid this you need to opt in to the browser emulation feature using the documented registry key.

You can find more info about this on the link bellow
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25843958/3636228

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did what described in the link but i haven't any result. Besides of this, my app is supposed to be an android apk so this solution doesn't much in this case

Comment: What values did you use in your registry? Did you use 9000 or 9999 as stated directly in the SO answer? If so do you realize that these are to prevent IE9 to go into compatibility mode? You should have also read linked documentation that also contains values for latest IE versions. As for you mentioning android. If you are developing an android app you should have mentioned that in your question right from the start.

Comment: I tried 9999. As for Android i mention in my question that is a multi device app. Thanks again

Comment: Value of 9999 means that webpages are displayed in IE 9 standard mode. But I'm guessing that that specific webpage requires at least displaying webpage in IE10 or IE11 mode. Check the linked documentation for proper values.