# Layout of Microsoft OAuth login wrong

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, twebbrowser

I'm opening the Microsoft OAuth login page inside a FMX TWebBrowser component and the layout of the page is wrong. Components are not aligned correctly and buttons are not shown in full. I'm doing this on a HDPI screen.

[image: Image of login window]

After setting mode to 11011 the windows opens as follows:

[Using 11011 for emulation mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAlV2.png)

Comment: Platform? Android?

Comment: Question author is mentioning HDPI screen which leads me to believe that this could still be on Windows desktop computer with High Resolution monitor. And if his application isn't configured properly for DPI Awareness and his TWebBrowser component is running in compatibility mode it could result in Web page not showing correctly.For instructions on how to prevent TWebBrowser running in compatibility mode check [How to have Delphi TWebbrowser component running in IE9 mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25843958/3636228)

Comment: This is on Windows 10, 32 bits application, Delphi 10.3.1.
Changing the value under FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION does not make any difference, unfortunately. Btw. a normal Windows VCL application does not have this problem.

Comment: @KeesVermeulen Per the [`TWebBrowser` documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.WebBrowser.TWebBrowser): "*On Windows target platforms (WIN32 and WIN64), TWebBrowser may incorrectly display some Web pages if a Web site uses JavaScript dialog boxes, panels, and other elements for various purposes. To work around this issue, your application should display Web pages in the **IE11 edge mode** using the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION feature of Internet Explorer.*" Which emulation mode did you try that didn't work for you?

Comment: I tried various mode values (11000, 11001) but none of them solved the issue. From the manual I learned that mode should be set to 11011. This makes things better but still not perfect.