# View Web Console When Using TWebBrowser

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

I am using a `TWebBrowser` to display a web page that is created in Vue, but I currently have no way to debug situations where functionality of the page works in a browser (IE and Chrome) but does not work from the `TWebBrowser`. I am looking for a way to access the web console or dev tools from within Delphi when displaying a `TWebBrowser` so that I can determine what exactly is preventing functionality of a page from working.

I have tried to implement a `TDeveloperConsoleMessageReceiver` class that uses the `IDeveloperConsoleMessageReceiver` interface. This class is created when the `TWebBrowser` is initialized. Then on `TWebBrowserDocumentComplete` I implemented the following function:

```
procedure TTTWebBrowser.WebBrowserDocumentCompleted(ASender: TObject; const pDisp: IDispatch; const URL: OleVariant);
var
   Target : IOleCommandTarget;
   Action : Cardinal;
   Params : OleVariant;
const
   IDM_ADDCONSOLEMESSAGERECEIVER = 3800;
   CGID_MSHTML: TGUID = '{DE4BA900-59CA-11CF-9592-444553540000}';
begin
   CallUserDocumentCompletedEvent(pDisp, URL);
   if Assigned(WebBrowser.Document) then begin
     Target := IOleCommandTarget(WebBrowser.Document);
     Action := IDM_ADDCONSOLEMESSAGERECEIVER;
     Params := EmptyParam;
     Target.Exec(@CGID_MSHTML, Action, OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT, IDeveloperConsoleMessageReceiver(DeveloperConsole), Params);
   end;
end;
```

Where `DeveloperConsole` is the `DeveloperConsoleMessageReceiver` class created on initialization. When the above function is run I get an access violation on the `Exec`.

How would I properly utilize `DeveloperConsoleMessageReceiver` or is there another way to debug a `TWebBrowser` from within Delphi?

Comment: Not an answer but normally functionality between The activeX component (Twebbrowser is a wrapper) and IE is the same. One caveat is that TWebbrowser starts in IE7 mode, causing most modern webpages to malfunction. You must set the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION flag to change this mode. More info can be found here

Comment: And don't forget about the good old `alert()` function.

Comment: @Olivier: Yes, but that will only work if you have the webpage contents under control.

Comment: By Default TBwebBrowser is working in IE7 Compatibility Mode. In order to make it run in Full Mode you need to opt in to the Browser emulation. You can read on how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25843958/3636228). After this webapges should be working in TWebBroswer same as they do in Internet Explorer.

Comment: I verified the browser is in IE11 mode and made sure the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION registry is set to 11000. Almost all functionality is the same between IE and the Delphi browser. Alerts, Tables, Etc show up just fine but I am trying to leverage this draggable library found [here](https://sortablejs.github.io/Vue.Draggable/#/simple) and the actual dragging of components is what works in IE but not in the Delphi browser.

Answer (score 0):

I use `NavigateComplete2` event and it works.
Here is my code:

```pascal
procedure TMainForm.WBNavigateComplete2(ASender: TObject;
  const pDisp: IDispatch; var URL: OleVariant);
const
  CGID_MSHTML: TGUID = '{DE4BA900-59CA-11CF-9592-444553540000}';
  IDM_ADDCONSOLEMESSAGERECEIVER = 3800;
var
  vin, vout: OleVariant;
begin
  if FDebugConsole then // Call it only once
    Exit;
  vout := Null;
  vin := Self as IDeveloperConsoleMessageReceiver;
  (WB.Document as IOleCommandTarget).Exec(@CGID_MSHTML, IDM_ADDCONSOLEMESSAGERECEIVER, OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT
    ,vin, vout);
  FDebugConsole := True;
end;
```

You have to call `IDM_ADDCONSOLEMESSAGERECEIVER` only once and later you can navigate to other pages and console messages will continue to arrive. My main form implements `IDeveloperConsoleMessageReceiver` interface.