# Different behavior when executing same IIM macro from "iMacros Component for .net" and when executing in iMacros editor/browser

Tags: imacros

I'm executing the following macro from inside VB.net using the iMacros component for .NET

```
VERSION BUILD=10.4.28.1074
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
URL GOTO=http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=6900914
SET !WAITPAGECOMPLETE YES 
WAIT SECONDS=10 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=H1 ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
```

This retrieves the name of the manuscript from IEEE Xplore. This works perfectly from inside the iMacros browser/editor. But, when executing the script from inside Vb.net, it gives me a "#EANF#" (Extraction Anchor Not Found).

I'm confounded.

Comment: check if your macro in vb.net can even load the page source

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.

The difference in behavior was because the site (here, IEEE Xplore), does not allow browsing from old browsers. Now, the iMacro browser works under IE 7's name. All you need to do is to add your program to the "browser emulation list", thus morphing your iMacros component browser to "look" like a newer browser for those websites that need it.

You'll find all the details on how to do that here:
[How do I turn off Compatibility View on the IE WebBrowserControl in a WinForms app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717055/how-do-i-turn-off-compatibility-view-on-the-ie-webbrowsercontrol-in-a-winforms-a)