# Can I hide the compatibility notification when using google maps in webbrowser control in .Net Desktop Application

Tags: c#, winforms, google-maps

I made a program that use the new google maps in c# but when opened, I get a notification concerning the compatibility of IE. (See image)
Any idea to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Would you please paste error in English?

Answer (score 2):

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717055/how-do-i-turn-off-compatibility-view-on-the-ie-webbrowsercontrol-in-a-winforms-a)

In general, WebBrowser control always runs in compatibility mode and the only way to disable it is to edit registry.

Another option is to use other control (not based on IE), like http://sourceforge.net/projects/webkitdotnet/

Comment: @Giovanny And no worry, you can do it in your c# code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your responses. 
I'm going to analyze which is more faster for me. But perhaps I'll end using openstreet maps.