# How to change minimum required platform from IE7 to IE9 in VC++ application

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, jqplot

I have IE9 installed on my Windows 7 machine.

1. Using this version of IE, when I view my local HTML page containing
   jqPlot graphs, everything is responsive (graph rendering and zooming
   are very quick).
2. If I set the browser's Browser Mode (F12 -> Browser Mode) to IE7 or
   IE8, the page becomes dramatically unresponsive (expected).

I'm currently working on an MFC application using VC++ 2008.  The application defines IE7 as its minimum required platform as follows:

```
In targetver.h

...
#ifndef _WIN32_IE               // Specifies that the minimum required platform is Internet Explorer 7.0.
#define _WIN32_IE 0x0700        // Change this to the appropriate value to target other versions of IE.
#endif
```

What I'd like to do is to target IE9 instead because when the application navigates to my local HTML page, any operations done to the page are very slow (like case 2 above).

Does anybody know how to do that?  I've tried setting  "_WIN32_IE" to "0x0900" but that doesn't seem to make any difference.  Are there any settings I need to change?

Comment: You target IE9 but it doesn't mean you require IE9 to view an HTML page. That define lets you use features (from API) introduced with IE9 (if any). If you require IE9 to be installed you have to check it by yourself (from registry, I suppose) when application starts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to put the WebBrowser control into IE9 into standards?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097593/how-to-put-the-webbrowser-control-into-ie9-into-standards)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

Adding

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" >
```

to the head section of my HTML file does seem to improve the overall performance.

I've done some speed tests around the piece of JavaScript code that takes most time:

```
var start = (new Date).getTime();
for (var i = 0; i < targetPlots.length; i++) {
    targetPlots[i].replot();
    controllerPlots[i].replot();
}
var diff = (new Date).getTime() - start;
alert(diff);
```

**Before adding the meta tag**

```
diff ≈ 6342 ms
```

**After adding the meta tag**

```
diff ≈ 394 ms
```

**With standalone IE9**

```
diff ≈ 173 ms
```

394 ms isn't too bad.

Thanks for the pointer!