# C# win. form - How to make XHTML support in webbrowser control?

Tags: c#, winforms, xhtml, gmail, webbrowser-control

Currently i am facing a crisis here.

The problem is that when i try to open **G-Mail** with the default **WebBrowser** control of windows form it says that browser does not support newer version of **HTML** which is **XHTML**.

So, can anybody suggest me a way how to open newer version of **G-Mail** in **WebBrowser** control or how can you make the **WebBrowser** support **XHTML**?

Comment: FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18333459/1768303

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WebBrowser control in C# may be rendering in IE7 mode. To fix this your target machine would have to have a newer version of IE. In addition if you need to force a particular rendering mode you can add a value for your app in the following registry entries:

On Windows 32 bit or 64 bit machine
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION

On Windows 64 bit with a 32bit executable
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION

You will need to add a DWORD value whose name is the name of your app.

Please refer to the [MSDN Document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx) for the values.

Below is an example:

[image: Modifying Registry Results]

Here is GMAIL Running in the webbrowsercontrol

[image]

Comment: i think this might work just need to know from where did you get this knowledge about the problem? from internet or from any software courses?

Comment: Had this issue before, so I knew what to look for. Here are some helpful links. 

[Rick Strahl named Web Browser Control – Specifying the IE Version](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version)

Oldest entry I can find on this is from an MSDN blog post 
[MSDN Original Entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/03/10/more-ie8-extensibility-improvements.aspx)

This is entry on [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796070/change-default-webbrowser-rendering-mode-in-c-sharp) is not too detailed.

Comment: Mr. Luis is there any way to open newer version of gmail without upgrading to new IE because in XP it does not support newer IE.