# chartjs; cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, chart.js

What I'm trying to do is use chartjs to create a Bar chart. The data is retrieved via $.ajax. And JSON data retrieved from $.ajax will be added later to dataset. However, when I'm about to create a chartjs. There is an error from Chart.js library:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

I have checked all the data after finished loading the ajax .There is no problem with the JSON (I've already check the console). Moreover, when I checked the `myBarChart` type is reported as undefined. Even I already assigned a new chartjs to itself after I finished retrive JSON data.

Here is a JavaScript Code:

```
var driverCode, driverPointsGained = "";
var exLabel = new Array();
var exPoints = new Array();
var chartData;
var myBarChart;
var ctx = document.getElementById("driverStandingChart").getContext("2d");
//var ctx = $("#driverStandingChart").get(0).getContext("2d");

Chart.defaults.global.responsive = true;

function addChartData(codename, pointsgained) {
    chartData = {
        label: codename,
        datasets: [
            {
                fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
                highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
                highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                data: pointsgained
            }
        ]
    };
    return chartData;
}

$("#testAjaxLoading").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/driverStandings.json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.info(data);

            for (var i = 0; i <= data.MRData.total-1; i++) {

                driverCode = data.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings[i].Driver.code;
                driverPointsGained = data.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings[i].points;

                console.info("code: " + driverCode + " points: " + driverPointsGained);

                //push data to array
                exLabel.push(driverCode);
                exPoints.push(driverPointsGained);
            }

            addChartData(exLabel,exPoints);

            console.log(chartData);

            myBarChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(chartData);

            alert("finished retrieve data");
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    });
});
```

Full code with HTML: https://gist.github.com/sancowinx/31b6289b7f28908db0c1

For the JSON data, I use an API from [Ergast API](http://ergast.com/mrd/) to get a JSON Results.

edit: adding Stack Trace:

[image]
$.ajax.success is actually `myBarChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(chartData);`

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't run your sample without your `f1.js` file dependency. :/

Comment: Also, it would be a lot easier if you pasted the stack trace for the error: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#viewing-exception-stack-trace

Comment: @CullenJ Added stacktrace. Actually for f1.js is not quite related to this problem. f1.js was for retrieving other result. However, you can look for f1.js source [here](https://gist.github.com/sancowinx/62bd7eea1f28b4dcbbb5)

Answer (score 2):

Your stack trace tells me that either `ctx` or `chartData` is undefined. My guess is that it's `ctx` if you've already checked chartData. (Verify this using `console.log`.) Perhaps this is the answer if that's the case: [canvas.getContext("2d") is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17321856/canvas-getcontext2d-is-undefined)

If that's not the case, then an element that ChartJS was looking for in your JSON was undefined. You'll have to look through the documentation to see what element is missing if that's the case.