# X-UA-Compatible doesn't work in C# WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer, ie8-compatibility-mode

I have webpage loaded in winforms WebBrowser control. That page need to be rendered in IE8 mode so I set `X-UA-Compatible` to `IE=8`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="pl" lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" >
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="PRAGMA" content="NO-CACHE" />
```

Unfortunately when I check user agent I still have MSIE 7.0. What can be the reason that X-UA-Compatible is ignored. When I open my page directly in IE9 all is well - document mode is switched to IE8.

My user agent:

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097593/how-to-put-the-webbrowser-control-into-ie9-into-standards might help

Comment: I known that but I would like to have IE=edge for all pages except that one.

Comment: it looks like you only have ie7 installed....

Answer (score 0):

"X-UA-Compatible" only affects the WebBrowser controls content mode, but not the UserAgent Header it would send. (see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patricka/2015/01/12/controlling-webbrowser-control-compatibility/)

Also, the UserAgent header is part of the HTTP request, which would have already been transmitted by the time the server starts sending its response, including any "X-UA-Compatible" value.