# TWebBrowser + CSS (Bootstrap/FontAwesome)

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

I'm on Windows 10, developing some app with TWebBrowser, and I had plan to use jQuery / [BootStrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and some other CSS like [FontAwesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/)

All these are perfectly compatible with Internet Explorer, at least latest versions. Anyway, the TWebBrowser inside my app, doesn't appear to work with simple html code like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
   </head>
  <body>
<span id="text1"><i class="fa fa-user fa-2x"></i> - Personal Profile Update</span>

  </body>
</html>
```

This code should show an user icon from FontAwesome, but doesn't appear anything.

The application code is very simple, I just put WebBrowser on my Form, and on FormShow I do:

```
  WebBrowser1.Navigate('http://localhost/');
```

But like I said, no icon is displayed. And this is just one example, I noted that Bootstrap html forms styles, jQuery carrousel, doesn't works too... I thought WebBrowser was just like Internet Explorer control, but looks like it doesn't. Is there any easy solution to make it compatible with this stuff?

Comment: the microsoft activeX webbrowser (for wich Twebbrowser a mere wrapper is) runs by default in IE7 mode. You need to force edge mode via meta equiv tag or by adding a registry key.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put the WebBrowser control into IE9 into standards?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097593/how-to-put-the-webbrowser-control-into-ie9-into-standards)

Comment: and another one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25843845/how-to-have-delphi-twebbrowser-component-running-in-ie9-mode

Comment: Oh yes, I did what you said on the meta tag, and it worked... Not sure if will fix all the compatibility problems, but I think is ok.

Comment: Just put edge, it works from IE8 which should be long dead now :)