# Display Differences when loading local HTML Page

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

I have come across an issue when I add a `TWebBrowser` to a Delphi form and then load a webpage either from file, i.e. `wb1.Navigate('file://myhtml.html');` or navigate to the exact page stored on a website, i.e. `wb1.navigate('http://mysite/myhtml.html');`

It seems to process the CSS differently whether I load the page locally or from the website in IE itself!

I have made sure the page has `<!DOCTYPE html>` which is meant to force IE9 as a minimum from what I have read.

Anyone seen anything like this before?

This is what it looks like if I load the page using `TWebBrowser`:

[image]

In IE, it displays the data correctly side by side horizontally.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It is a Q&A site. What exactly is your question?

Comment: "I have made sure the page has which"... missing a word there. This post would be improved by a) providing the CSS in question b) a screenshot of how the page is supposed to look.

Comment: Have you tried opening these pages in IE directly. By default IE disables some web page content usually referred as `Active content` when such page is loaded from local file. Also until your application is properly registered in Registry the content in TWebBrowser will always be shown in IE7 compatibility mode. A way to overcome this is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25843958/3636228

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes it was the compatibility mode. I had seen that article but was not 100% sure if there was another way to do it or if it would resolve it. The downside is I now need to alter the registry for my app. but so long as the security is ok, it should be fine.

Comment: This may also help: [Controlling WebBrowser Control Compatibility](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patricka/2015/01/12/controlling-webbrowser-control-compatibility/)

Comment: JCoultier, you don't have to change the registry if you have the webpage under control, just add meta tag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` to the head section...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put the WebBrowser control into IE9 into standards?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097593/how-to-put-the-webbrowser-control-into-ie9-into-standards)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. It was the compatibility mode that was the issue.

Comment: So, how did you fix it? Please include that in the answer so that it benefits others.