# Origin of C# WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

I am working on a C# application which uses an embedded WebBrowser control to display some HTML content. I want to test whether installing IE9 http://windows.microsoft.com/ie9 will effect my application.

The MSDN blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/03/18/webbrowser-control-rendering-modes-in-ie8.aspx states that the WebBrowser control defaults to IE7 rendering. However, I want to know what binary is actually being used to do the IE7 rendering.

I think the WebBrowser control could be packaged with:

- the version of IE included with Windows (e.g. IE8 with Windows 7)
- the newest version of IE installed in Windows (e.g. IE9)
- the .NET runtime, my application uses .NET 2.0
- Visual Studio, my application is built using VS2008

Which of these is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .net winforms webbrowser is just a wrapper for MSIE's own browser control (in shdocvw.dll). If you have IE8 installed, it uses IE8. If you have IE9 installed it uses IE9. For some silly reason they decided to have it fall back to IE7 rendering mode.

You can override that with a meta tag in the page header, or with a registry key. See [MSIEs WebBrowser control hosted in winforms app runs in compatibility mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554314/#3571913)

Comment: Just remember to set it back to original state when your app closes and add reverting to windows loading so that you won't screw up other programs.

Comment: @Migol Set what back? The page header directive is something contained within the web page you're loading. The registry key is set _per_ _application_ so under normal circumstances neither will affect other apps.