# Controlling IE rendering engine for System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser?

Tags: .net, winforms, controls, webbrowser-control

When using the `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` control, is there a way to control which version of IE rendering engine it will use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MSIEs WebBrowser control hosted in winforms app runs in compatibility mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554314/msies-webbrowser-control-hosted-in-winforms-app-runs-in-compatibility-mode)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regarding IE9 WebBrowser control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612255/regarding-ie9-webbrowser-control)

Comment: Thanks for the duplicate link guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe IE does this by manipulating the request `User-Agent` string.

```
compatible; MSIE 7.0;
compatible; MSIE 8.0;
compatible; MSIE 9.0;
```

So to use different rendering engines with WebBrowser you would need to do something similar. Unfortunately getting access to the `User-Agent` in [WebBrowser is not easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250877/net-native-application-equivalent-of-modify-headers-firefox-addon/7296229#7296229). You can do it if you extend the actual Com component, rather than using the .Net control.

```
public class ExtendedWebBrowser : WebBrowser
{
    ...

    void BeforeNavigate(object pDisp, ref object url, ref object flags,
                       ref object targetFrameName, ref object postData, 
                       ref object headers, ref bool cancel)
    {
         if (!headers.Contains("X-RequestFlag")
         {
             headers += "X-RequestFlag: true\r\n";

             // append user-agent header here
             headers["User-Agent"] = ...;

             // cancel current request
             cancel = true;

             // re-request with amended details
             Navigate((string)url, (string)targetFrameName, (byte[])postData, 
                      (string)headers);
         }
         else
         {
             base.BeforeNavigate(...);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Most solutions I've seen involve editing the registry, or they require that you have access to the web page's source code. This requires neither - great solution imho.